# 2 amp transformer alternatives

Tags: transformer

Beginner here, please bear with me. I'm following instructions to modify a popcorn popper for coffee roasting: http://popperyii.blogspot.com/

It looks like it requires a 25.2 VCT 2A transformer ([schematic](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_ZByKAI28tEg/TS55KCXUdAI/AAAAAAAAC5A/8gApmDA5r3w/s1600/PopperyIIElecSchematicv7.jpg)). However, Radio Shack no longer sells these. Are there any alternatives? Would a 12v 2A "cellphone charger" transformer work in place of that?

Comment: No. Look somewhere else for the transformer.

Comment: I'm not sure why the specify exactly 25.2. I guess anything between 24-28 volt would do, which should be easier to find, especially 24. Someone else can comment if they think this will break anything.

Comment: Thanks @pipe, there's a shop here that carries this: http://www.mpja.com/24V-2A-Center-Tapped-12-0-12-Transformer/productinfo/27844+TR/ would that do the trick? Is the primary 110v and the secondary 24v?

Comment: Look under the blue "Detailed Description" bar on the MPJA page you linked to for the transformer spec's.  There's even a little schematic you can click on which will show you how to hook the thing up so you don't accidentally destroy the universe. ;)

Answer (score 2):

SE isn't for "shop for me" questions, but it sounds like you just need one of the basic tools-of-the-trade: awareness that a supply network exists.  For general electronics, try Mouser, Digi-Key, Arrow, Jameco, Newark, Galco, and often you get lucky on Amazon (Prime, yay) or eBay.

For this particularly, you have one more option.  24V transformers are widely used for control voltage in heating and cooling applications, which opens up a wide variety of products from another tranche of suppliers.  For instance your local heating/cooling supply, some code-electrical distributors, Lowes/Menards/HomeDepot, Grainger, and numerous products on Amazon.

This is why I often recommend people homebrew stuff out of 24v transformers and 24v-coil relays, because they are readily available dirt cheap out of the heating-cooling parts bin.   Need a 30A relay capable of interrupting a big inductive load?  A/C relays.

Answer (score 1):

A 12V 2A transformer won't work, but two with their secondaries phased properly and wired in series will.

The transformer doesn't need to be center-tapped, and a 24V 2A secondary will work fine.

Also, the bridge is shown wired wrong on the schematic. It should look like this:

[image]